# Corrupted BIOS files and lack of OS specific BIOS files on the internet

Tags: boot, bios, windows-11

My HP Pavilion x360 Convertible Laptop PC 14-dh0101tu, a few days back did not boot and instead showed a black screen, the fans were running and the display was on (though it was blank). I tried restarting it, going into the BIOS menu by pressing the f10 key, but the laptop just showed a text stating that F10 key is used for the BIOS menu in the bottom left corner and did not boot up, I further tried pressing the power button and the Windows-B key combination and the laptop showed the following message:

Screenshot:
[image]

Therefore I tried to get the BIOS files from this link on the HP website. But the link only allows me to download drivers for Windows-10, whereas my laptop runs Windows-11.

I have asked a question regarding the lack of Windows-11 BIOS files on the HP Website but have not received any response yet. Therefore, **is there any other way for me fix this problem.**

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> the link only allows me to download drivers for Windows-10, whereas my laptop runs Windows-11

That doesn't matter; the BIOS (system firmware) **is not OS-specific in the first place.** The only effect on selecting the OS when downloading a firmware image is in what updating/flashing tools get offered together with it – and realistically, you'll likely get exactly the same "BIOS update" app whether you select Windows 11, Windows 10, or even Windows 8. (And if your goal is to put the firmware image on a USB stick for recovery, then you won't be using the regular flashing tools so that's moot anyway.)

(For that matter, drivers written for Windows 10 will work in Windows 11, too. Windows 11 is very nearly the same OS as Windows 10 – it is not significantly more different than, say, the differences between Windows 10.19H2 and Windows 10.22H2, so if you expect "Windows 10" drivers to work the same across all of its releases, then they will work just the same in Windows 11 as well.)

Comment: Thanks, thus can I select anyone of the windows versions given in this link: https://support.hp.com/in-en/drivers/hp-pavilion-14-dh0000-x360-convertible-pc/model/28494042 ?

Comment: Yes, just choose whichever offers you the most recent version of the files you need. The option "Windows 10 (64-bit)" offers BIOS image F.24 Rev.A dated Dec 8, 2023.